# NHibernate: Using createSQLQuery with one-to-one mapping causing extra queries

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I am using the following code in my query

```
var query = session.CreateSQLQuery(sqlQuery)
    .AddEntity("g", typeof(AllegroGoalContract))
    .AddJoin("gd", "g.GoalDetail")
    .SetInt32("max", max.Value)
    .SetGuid("callerId", ServerContext.Current.TeamMemberUniqueId)
    .SetInt32("ver", lastChange);
```

It is using the following mapping:

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" schema="Methodology" >
    <class name="SixDisciplines.AllegroGoalContract, SixDisciplines" table="Goal" lazy="false">
        .
        .
        <one-to-one name="GoalDetail" class="SixDisciplines.AllegroGoalDetailContract, SixDisciplines" constrained="false"/>
        .
        .
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

And here is a small sample of the SQL.  The actual SQL is using features specific to Sql Server, but this simplified SQL demonstrates the same issue:

```
SELECT
g.UniqueId AS {g.UniqueId},
g.Description AS {g.Description},
g.StatusId AS {g.Status},
gd.UniqueId AS {gd.UniqueId},
gd.ActualEnd AS {gd.ActualEnd}
FROM Methodology.Goal g
LEFT JOIN Methodology.GoalDetail gd ON g.UniqueId = gd.UniqueId
```

Now my sql query returns all of the AllegroGoalContract instances along with the GoalDetail one-to-one association.  Notice that the mapping for the one-to-one association has constrained="false" set indicating that there does not have to be a GoalDetail for every AllegroGoalContract.

When I run this code, I see my query run but then I see nhibernate issue a separate query for every AllegroGoalContract instance where my query returned null for the  GoalDetail.  I suspect this is because nhibernate does not know if the null was returned because it was a lazy load or because it really does not exist.

So how can I tell nhibernate that the null from the CreateSQLQuery call for GoalDetails really means that they are not there so don't go and try and fetch them again.

Comment: Why are you using CreateSQLQuery?

Comment: Because this is a complex query that is using specific features of SQL Server.

Comment: So stuff not shown in the above query?

Comment: Yes.  I did not go into the details of the SQL query since it is not significant to the use of CreateSQLQuery.

Answer (score 1):

The NHibernate mapping node - `<one-to-one/>` has an attribute called fetch, default value is - select which make a separate query for each adjunct entity.
If you want NHibernate to use SQL Join change to -

```
<one-to-one name="GoalDetail" class="SixDisciplines.AllegroGoalDetailContract, SixDisciplines" constrained="false" fetch="join" outer-join="true"/>
```

Comment: I tried using the fetch="join" and it did not have any affect on how it interpreted the results of the CreateSQLQuery call.  It still issues addition separate queries.

Comment: Try to add also 'outer-join="true"' to the '<one-to-one/>' mapping.

Comment: Still the same result as before.

Comment: Why do make another join in your CreateSQLQuery?

Comment: Are you referring to the .AddJoin("gd", "g.GoalDetail")?  I am using this to populate the AllegroGoalContract GoalDetail association that is returned by the SQL.  Is there a different CreateSQLQuery syntax that I should be using instead of AddJoin?

Comment: Sorry Mr. Mush, but I am not following you.  I thought I needed the AddJoin() in order to let nhibernate know that I would be loading the GoalDetail association.  Are you saying AddJoin() is not needed? Would I need to use AddEntity()? I added a simplified example of the SQL query that I am using to the original post.